# reLoad External Page onLinkClick via ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, captcha

This is the link

```
<a href="javascript:loadCaptcha();">Reload</a>
```

I want to click it and load an external file via ajax and jquery. In my page header, i have following javascript code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        loadCaptcha();
    });
    function loadCaptcha()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'captcha.php',
            data: "",
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){
                $('#captcha').html(res);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I want to reload captcha.php on click of that link. Onpageload the file captcha.php is loading in id #captcha - but on that link click its not reloading.

captcha.php code

```
<?php
$capt = generate_captcha();
echo '<img src="captcha.jpg" id="imgcaptcha" name="imgcaptcha" alt="'.$capt.'" style="max-width: 110px; max-height: 35px;" title="Captcha"/><input type="hidden" name="captchacode" id="captchacode" value="'.$capt.'" />';

function generate_captcha()
    {
        $number= rand(11111, 99999);
        $width = 110;
        $height= 35;
        //create image using imagecreate php function
        $img = imagecreate($width, $height);
            $backcolor = imagecolorallocatealpha(
                      $img,
                      hexdec( substr( 'FFFFFF', 0, 2 ) ),
                      hexdec( substr( 'FFFFFF', 2, 2 ) ),
                      hexdec( substr( 'FFFFFF', 4, 2 ) ),
                      127 * ( 100 - 100 ) / 100
                    );
        imagefill($img, 0, 0, $backcolor);
            //create line color
        $linescolor = imagecolorallocatealpha(
                      $img,
                      hexdec( substr( '333333', 0, 2 ) ),
                      hexdec( substr( '333333', 2, 2 ) ),
                      hexdec( substr( '333333', 4, 2 ) ),
                      127 * ( 100 - 70 ) / 100
                    );
        //generate different lines  
        for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {
            imageline($img, mt_rand(0,110), mt_rand(0,35),
             mt_rand(0,110), mt_rand(0,35), $linescolor);
            }
        //Font file path
        $font_path = "jokerman.ttf";
        //create color for font
        $font_color = imagecolorallocatealpha(
                      $img,
                      hexdec( substr( '000000', 0, 2 ) ),
                      hexdec( substr( '000000', 2, 2 ) ),
                      hexdec( substr( '000000', 4, 2 ) ),
                      127 * ( 100 - 100 ) / 100
                    );
        //add characters to the image
        imagettftext($img, 22, 0, 5, 28, $font_color, $font_path, $number);
        //store image
        imagejpeg($img, "captcha.jpg", 100);
        return $number;
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE: chrome is showing updated image, firefox and ie are not updating image. cache problem. I have used no cache via php header but no luck.**

Please advise.

Comment: I think your problem sits elsewhere...

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am able to load file, but i am not able to reload it via a link by using same function.

Comment: Can you provide us the code from your captcha.php?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. captcha.php code added.

Comment: **UPDATE:** The captcha image is changing, but the changed image is not displaying. On reload > old image stays there, but if i validate that, it validates invalid because it has changed...it is just not refreshing. How to refresh it when I click reload.

Comment: Only firefox is not updating image. Image is changing and recreating by script but firefox is showing old version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onclick` instead of `href="javascript:loadCaptcha();"`

```
<a onclick="loadCaptcha();">Reload</a>
```

OR

```
<a id="reloadCaptcha">Reload</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on("click", "#reloadCaptcha", loadCaptcha);
</script>
```

Comment: try to bind click event by jquery

Comment: Tried this one, now...still not reloading.

Answer (score 0):

IE and Firefox won't refresh captcha image due to cache problem. Work around is to delete the captcha image everytime and create new captcha image with unique name. Because name will be unique, captcha will be refreshed and FF will reload the image because its new.

I have fixed this issue with recreating unique captcha image everytime and calling that unique image on reload.